# Google Earth Engine extract data from Sentinel-5P

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, sentinel-5p

I would like to extract Near Real-Time Nitrogen Dioxide from Sentinel-5P for all countries. The output (in csv format) however does not show the Nitrogen Dioxide information and date (only country ID is displayed). The world shapefile can be found from: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/tronganhtrinh/worldsp

```
// Define which year to work with
var yr = 2020;

// Range for the Landsat images
var Range = ee.DateRange(yr + '-05-28', yr + '-05-31'); 

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
  .select('NO2_column_number_density')
  .filterBounds(worldsp)
  .filterDate(Range);

function tabulate(i){
  return worldsp.map(function (f){
    var r = i.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
      geometry: f.geometry(), 
      scale: 500,
      bestEffort:true,
      maxPixels:1e9});
    return ee.Feature(null, {
      name: f.get('OBJECTID'),
      index: i.get('system:time_start')});
  });}

var resultstable = collection.map(tabulate).flatten();

Export.table.toDrive(resultstable,'results','csv');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of your code

```
var r = i.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  geometry: f.geometry(), 
  scale: 500,
  bestEffort:true,
  maxPixels:1e9});
return ee.Feature(null, {
  name: f.get('OBJECTID'),
  index: i.get('system:time_start')});
```

you are not using `r` at all, so nothing from it is included in the result (in fact, it's not even computed at all). Try instead

```
return ee.Feature(null, {
  name: f.get('OBJECTID'),
  index: i.get('system:time_start'),
}).setMulti(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works well. However, it took me more than 2 hours to get the data (only for two days: 1st and 2nd January). Is there a better (faster) way to extract the data in GEE?

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
  .select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
  .filterBounds(worldsp)
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-01-02');

function tabulate(i){
  return worldsp.map(function (f){
    var r = i.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
      geometry: f.geometry(), 
      scale: 500,
      bestEffort:true,
      maxPixels:1e9});
return ee.Feature(null, {
  name: f.get('OBJECTID'),
  index: i.get('system:time_start'),
}).setMulti(r);
  });}

var resultstable = collection.map(tabulate).flatten();

Export.table.toDrive(resultstable,'results','csv');
```